# getSqlMapClientTemplate() resulting in an object without an SqlMapClient

Tags: java, spring, maven, sqlmap

What are the requirements to ensure that getSqlMapClientTemplate() results in a working object?

I am building a maven project on eclipse, and writing JUnit tests. Upon running the test, I run into a "No SqlMapClient specified" error on the highlighted line:

---

```
@Override
public SignIn getpassforloginAttempt(String emailid, String token,
        int flag, String loginSrc, String ext_userId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SignIn signin = new SignIn();
    try {
        //Make a hashmap to store arguments
        HashMap params = new HashMap();
        params.put("EmailId", emailid);
        params.put("token", token);
        params.put("flag", flag);
        params.put("login_src", loginSrc);
        params.put("user_id_external", ext_userId);

        //SqlMapClientTemplate object used for data access via iBATIS SqlMapClient API
        //executes a mapped SQL insert statement
        template.insert("getpassforSignIn", params);
```

---

Which uses this object:

---

```
public class SignInServiceImpl extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements
    SignInService {

    SqlMapClientTemplate template = getSqlMapClientTemplate();
```

---

Spring [should handle the rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/support/SqlMapClientDaoSupport.html#getSqlMapClientTemplate()) given this bean:

---

```
<beans:bean id="sqlMapClient"
    class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource">
        <beans:ref local="dataSource" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:sqlMapConfig.xml" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userTestDao" class="com.pg.lms.dao.UserTestDao">
    <beans:property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

---

Which calls this resource path file:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
```

PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

```
<sqlMapConfig>

    <!-- USER_TABLE MAPPING WITH UserTable entity -->
    <sqlMap resource="login/SignUp.xml" />
    <sqlMap resource="login/SignIn.xml" />

    <sqlMap resource="course/AddCE.xml" />
    <sqlMap resource="course/MarketplaceCE.xml" />
    <sqlMap resource="course/modifyCe.xml" />
    <sqlMap resource="course/ViewCE.xml" />

    <sqlMap resource="accountprofile/Profile.xml" />
     <sqlMap resource="accountprofile/deleteaccount.xml" />

     <sqlMap resource="subscription/subscription.xml" />

    <sqlMap resource="pushnotifications/pushnotification.xml" />

    <sqlMap resource="promoevent/share.xml" />

    <sqlMap resource="emailtemplates/EmailTemplates.xml" />
</sqlMapConfig>
```

---

Leading to this parameterMap and procedure (actual procedure not shown):

---

```
<parameterMap class="java.util.Map" id="SignIn_attempt">
    <parameter property="EmailId" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="pass" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="confirmed" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="flag" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="token" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="id" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="fname" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="lname" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="type" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="status" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="year" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="is_active" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="token2" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="login_src" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="user_id_external" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="useridExternal" mode="OUT" />
    <parameter property="loginSrc" mode="OUT" />
</parameterMap>


<procedure id="getpassforSignIn" parameterMap="SignIn_attempt">

    call
    login_SignIn_attempt(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

</procedure>
```

---

What is going wrong? And how does one troubleshoot an issue like this?

Comment: If you want to post a code, post a code, don't post an image with the code.

Comment: @RomanC, fixed it, sorry about that!